# Executing a linux command in a shell script

Tags: unix

I am trying to execute a command, but the command is way too long, and is too long to run just from the command line. So i am trying to put it in a shell script, and then I can just run the shell script and it will execute the really long unix command.

Obviously I need the header, and then that is followed by the command. What syntax so I need to add so this shell script will work?

```
 #!/bin/sh
./mysqldump --defaults-file=../../conf/mysql.conf --single-transaction \
   --ignore-table=st.Event --ignore-table=st.TransferStatus  \
   --ignore-table=st.TransferConfiguration --ignore-table=st.TransferData \ 
   --ignore-table=st.logging_event --ignore-table=st.logging_event_exception \ 
   --ignore-table=st.logging_event_property \
   -u root -pXXXXXXXX st > /tmp/database_backup.sql
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have right there? Does it work?

Comment: (The backslashes don't change anything to your script, putting it all on one line is fine.)

Comment: Is this script in the same directory as `./mysqldump`? How are you calling it? What happens when you call it?

Comment: you need to be sure there are not trailing space, tabs, or other Hidden characters after your continuation char '\' at the end of each continuing line. Also, if you have created this on a windows machine that then transfered to a Linux, you should run `dos2unix`, as well as `chmod 755 myDumperScript.sh`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the `./`, also, you can create an alias for this command (http://linuxreviews.org/quicktips/alias/). Don't forget to `chmod +x` the `.sh` file once you get the command ready.

You might want to take a look at this sample here:
http://bash.cyberciti.biz/backup/backup-mysql-database-server-2/

```
MYSQLDUMP="$(which mysqldump)"
$MYSQLDUMP -u $MyUSER -h $MyHOST -p$MyPASS $db
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as syntax goes, your shell script seems fine to me...

What I would be careful about is all the relative paths in the script, more specifically `./mysqldump` and `../../conf/mysql.conf`. Using relative paths requires that the script is *always* executed from a specific directory in the filesystem. Using absolute paths makes the script safer, although it does bind it to a specific location.

If you insist on using relative paths, you can place the script in the directory it should be run from and then call *it* using an absolute path.

To run a script you should either make its file executable using `chmod +x` (or some variation thereof) or pass it as an argument to `sh` e.g. `sh /path/to/my/script.sh`.

We might be able to help more if you mentioned what the exact problem with your current script is...